# java8 installing issue on linux error: alternative path

Tags: kali-linux, java

**i have an issue on setup the java on my kali linux using vm on macboob Pro
im new on the system i have the issue that when i follow the command**

(a㉿kali)-[/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.8.0_371]
└─$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.8.0_371/bin/java" 0

**i dont have any problem , when i start to install the java compeller i gout the error below >**

─(a㉿kali)-[/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.8.0_371]
└─$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.8.0_371/bin/javac" 0
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.8.0_371/bin/javac doesn't exist

can someone kindly help me withe simple explain coz im not an pro in this matters im learning

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing a JRE (runtime) in the path not an JDK (development tools), the JRE does not contain the `javac` (compiler).

Hence the error because there is no command called `javac` in the `/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.8.0_371/bin/` directory.

I suggest you look in the `/usr/lib/jvm` directory for a `jdk1.8.0_371/bin` directory...